# Bypassing WS.Reputation.1 (Norton)

Tags: malware, windows

So, I tried to create a backdoor on my own using python (for a course), as veil kept getting detected. All went well on my windows 10 VM and my old windows 7 laptop. However, when I copied the .exe file to my windows 10 machine, Symantec detected it using "WS.Reputation.1" and moved it to quarantine.

Can someone tell me what exactly causes this to get triggered? Is there any way that I can increase its "reputation score"? Or maybe bypass this through code or pyinstaller arguments?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WS.Reputation.1** detects files and performs analysis on with data from Norton community of users (If you've installed Norton product, there is a checkbox requesting if you like to opt in to Norton community watch program'), the analysis are matched against the crowd data and a scoring are placed. If there's a low reputation score then therefore are likely to be security risks. The tech behind it are Norton's reputation-based security technology.

**Excerpt from Norton:**

> *The reputation-based system uses "the wisdom of crowds" (Symantec’s tens of millions of end users) connected to cloud-based intelligence
>   to compute a reputation score for an application, and in the process
>   identify malicious software in an entirely new way beyond traditional
>   signatures and behavior-based detection techniques.*

As for in depth explanation of how the technology works and how it gets triggered. It relies on a number of factors (based on what I know so far.)

**1. Newness**
How new is the file observed in the community.

**2. Digital Signature**
It looks for signed files. Custom or home grown application should be digitally signed with class three digital certificates.

**3. Heuristic**
What exactly does the file procedure calls. Does it write to registry? Start parent-child processes? Accessing windows protected folder?

Something you want to consider for reducing the chance of being detected. That said I believe over here is not a place to discuss in detail about "bypassing" any technologies.  :)

**What can you do as a tester or developer.**
You might want to reduce Norton protection level settings to allow FP-averse conditions or test environment. And also Age & Prevalence settings to allow "new" unknown files.

Secondly as you're developing a test file there's no need to submit to the AV team as a false positive. Plus you're testing a backdoor so no way they are adding that to a whitelist. But of course you may do your part in perhaps providing better detections for future AV detections.